# Importance sampling using Kullback-Liebler divergence.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, optimization, convex-analysis, information-theory

Suppose we maximize the following program:
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{v}_1^* = \arg\max_{\mathbf{v}} \sum_{\mathbf{x}} 1_{\{S(\mathbf{x})\geq \gamma_1\}} f(\mathbf{x;u})\ln f(\mathbf{ x;  v}),
\end{equation}
where $f(\cdot; \mathbf{v})$ is a Natural Exponential Family (NEF) parametrized by its mean vector $\mathbf{v}$.
Suppose further,
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{v}_2^* = \arg\max_{\mathbf{v}} \sum_{\mathbf{x}} 1_{\{S(\mathbf{x})\geq \gamma_2\}} f(\mathbf{x;u})\ln f(\mathbf{x; v}),
\end{equation}
where $\gamma_2>\gamma_1$. In general, $\gamma_i>\gamma_{i-1}, \; \forall i>1$. Moreover, we know that,

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\mathbf{x}}1_{\{S(\mathbf{x})\geq \gamma_i\}}f(\mathbf{x;u}) \leq \sum_{\mathbf{x}}1_{\{S(\mathbf{x})\geq \gamma_i\}}f(\mathbf{x;v_i^*}), \; \forall i=1,2,\dots,n.
\end{equation}

where $\{\gamma_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is strictly increasing in $i$.

I need to prove that,

\begin{equation}
    \sum_{\mathbf{x}} 1_{\{S(\mathbf{x})\geq \gamma_i\}}f(\mathbf{x;v_i^*}) \geq \sum_{\mathbf{x}} 1_{\{S(\mathbf{x})\geq \gamma_i\}}f(\mathbf{x;v_{i-1}^*}) \; \forall i=1,2,\dots, n.
\end{equation}